# Por que o comando 'cd' não funciona via ssh no GOCD?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, ssh, integração-contínua

Estou tentando rodar o comando abaixo no terminal do [GOCD](https://www.gocd.org/), porém sempre ocorre o erro:

**Comando**

```
ssh root@host 'cd /var/www/gda-frontend/ && docker-compose up -d --build'
```

**Erro**

> bash: cd /var/www/gda-frontend/ && docker-compose up -d --build: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

O diretório existe, porém ele não consegue rodar. E já há a conexão via ssh sem senha entre os dois.

Mesmo rodando somente o `cd`, sem o comando `docker-compose`, ocorre o erro.

Comment: Tente desta maneira: ssh root@host '/var/www/gda-frontend/docker-compose up -d --build' P.s: Não consigo comentar por isto postei em forma de pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui ver nada de errado, se o diretório realmente existe.
Com a conexão estabelecida, confirme se o diretório realmente existe e se o nome do mesmo está correto:

```
ssh root@host 'cd /var/www/ && ls'
```

O erro resposta é bem claro 'Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado'. Pode ser que o diretório seja em '/var/www/html/gda-frontend/', mas agora é apenas uma suposição minha.